# why does v-model on component using select element in vue js doen't work?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

iam trying to  create  a currency converter using vue js 3  and the  option api  and i am  struggling to  make my select  element  update when  the  reactive  data is changed ,  i  have two  component  the  child  component  that have a select  tag  in the template  this select  tag  is populated by looping over a currencies props and  i  want to  add v-model  on the child component  but it  don't work  as i expected

want  to  use v-model on a child component in order  to  retrieve the  value of the select tag inside the template and also  when i  change the value of the reactive data i want  the  select to  reflect thoses changes , precisely when i click on a swap  button i swap  the  value the  reactive data but that  is  not  reflected by the  childcomponent

there is the child component

```
<script >
  export default {
  props: ['modelValue','currencies'],
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  data() {
    return {
      compteur: 0
    }
  },
}
</script>
<template>
  <select  class="currency_selector"  :value="modelValue"
  @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" >
  <option   v-for="(value, currency) in currencies" :key="value.id" 
   :value="currency">
    {{ currency }}-{{value.currency_name}}
  </option>
</select>
 </template>
```

and there the parent

```
<script>
// import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import CurrencySelector from './components/CurrencySelector.vue';
export default {
  components: {
    CurrencySelector
  },
 
  data() {
    return {
      currencies_loaded: false,
     
      amount:null,
      timeoutId:null
      
    }
  },
  created(){

  fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/currencies/list')
  .then(response => {

    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json(); 
    } else {
      throw new Error('Request failed');
    }

  })
  .then(currencies => {
 
    this.currencies=currencies.data;
    this.currency_1=Object.keys(this.currencies)[7];
    this.currency_2=Object.keys(this.currencies)[0]
        
    this.currencies_loaded= true;

  })
  .catch(error => {
    
    console.error(error);
  });

  },
  
  mounted(){
    
   
  },

  methods: {
    amount_modified(event){
     
      clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
      
        this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        
          if(event.target.value){

            fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/exchange/pairs/${this.currency_1}/${this.currency_2}`)
            .then(response => {

              if (response.ok) {
                return response.json(); 
              } else {
                throw new Error('Request failed');
              }

            })
            .then(data => {
          

              console.log(data)

            })
            .catch(error => {
              
              console.error(error);
            });

          }


        }, 500);

    },
    swap_handler(){
      this.temp_currency=this.currency_1;
      this.currency_1=this.currency_2;
      this.currency_2=this.temp_currency;
    
    },
    
    convertion_init(event) {
     
    
  }
,
 
}
,

}

</script>
<template>
 <div id="main_container" v-if="currencies_loaded">
    <div id="selector_container"   >
      <input type="text" @input="amount_modified"  class="inputs" inputmode="decimal" autocomplete="off"  id="amount">

      <div class="inputs">

        <label for="currency_1">DE</label>

        <CurrencySelector  id="currency_1" :currencies="currencies"  v-model="currency_1"/>

      </div>
    <button  type="button" @click="swap_handler" id="swap_currencies">
      <img id="swap_arrow" src="./img/svgviewer-output.svg" alt="">

    </button>
   <div class="inputs">

    <label for="currency_2">VERS</label>

    <CurrencySelector  id="currency_2" :currencies="currencies" v-model="currency_2"/>

   </div>

  </div>
 </div>

</template>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: If you could make a working (or not working which is what the questions asks) example on https://play.vuejs.org/ (with constant values rather then fetch) this question would be quite a bit easier to answer

Comment: Looks like `currencies`, `currency_1` and `currency_2` are not declared in the `data` section, so they will not be reactive

Comment: i did it  but  how do  i  share the link here ?

Comment: Moritz Ringler
thank you so   I didn't even  saw it

Comment: and also i was wantering if in my  case it is better  to  use a watcher  or  @change event  in order to  trigger  a fetch  request to  retrieve the exchange  very  time a user select another currency

Comment: I want to  do  something similar to  this website https://www.xe.com/fr/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=250000&From=FRF&To=EUR

Comment: Yes, I think, change event should be used